# Retrieve jsp value in servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with the recovery of the values of my JSP in my Servlet.

My JSP contains one input and two select.

I would like to retrieve the values of these elements and pass them in my servlet, but the result in my servlet is still null.

```
String histoDate = request.getParameter("cDate");
String intervalleHeure = request.getParameter("cHeure");
String statut = request.getParameter("cStatut");
```

And in my JSP I create these elements in jQuery

```
"<label>Date : <input class='form-control' type='text' value='05/07/2018' placeholder='Cliquer pour choisir' id='histoDate' name='histoDate'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>"
"<label>Heure : <select id='demo-foo-filter-nbTrame' class='form-control selectpicker' id='intervalleHeure' name='intervalleHeure'>"
"<select id='demo-foo-filter-status' class='form-control selectpicker' id='statut' name='statut'>"
```

And I try to access my servlet with a function and I pass in argument the necessary values

```
function valeurHistorique(cDate, cHeure, cStatut){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Production/Maintenance/JSONHistorique",
            data: {
                histoDate: cDate,
                heure : cHeure,
                statut : cStatut
            },
```

My three values are still null in my servlet, I am really stuck. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you send ajax request parameters will be named as left part of object data.

**histoDate, heure, statut**.

Try it:

```
String histoDate = request.getParameter("histoDate");
String intervalleHeure = request.getParameter("heure");
String statut = request.getParameter("statut");
```

Also if you could see all parameters in `httpServletRequest.getParameterMap();`